# Is [7, 10) a subset of {7, 8, 9, 10}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm learning elementary set theory and so, in an effort to understand my reasoning, I'd like some feedback. I apologise if it's too basic - I'm barely starting out and don't want to get my foundation wrong.

I'm asked the following:

> Is it true that [7, 10) ⊆ {7, 8, 9, 10}?

I've dubbed {7, 8 , 9, 10} = A for simplicity's sake. The interval [7, 10) is composed of the numbers 7 ≤ x < 10, which include 7.1, 7.11, 7.222, and an infinite amount of numbers before 10. Meanwhile, A is composed of only four elements: 7,8,9,10. Simultaneously, elements of A are also present in the interval: 7, 8, 9 are, indeed, part of [7, 10) and of A. Would this be enough to consider [7, 10) ⊆ {7, 8, 9, 10} as true, or does the presence of other numbers (like those I listed above) disqualify the interval from being a subset of A?

Comment: No, the presence of other numbers (such as those you listed) disqualifies the interval from being a subset of $A$, because $A$ is a subset of $B$ means that **every** element of $A$ is also an element of $B$

Comment: Well, there are a **lot** of elements missing from set $A$ which are present in $[7,10)$. So you can't truly call this interval a subset of set $A$

Comment: Note that when you wrote $7\ge x>10$, you got both inequalities backwards: it should be $7\le x<10$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you for pointing it out. Already edited.

Answer (score 4):

$A = [7, 10)$

$B = \{7, 8, 9, 10 \}$

$A$ is not a subset of $B$ because $7.1 \in A, 7.1 \notin B $ ,

$B$ is a not a subset of $A$ because $10 \in B, 10 \notin A$

But $B$ is a subset of $[7, 10]$

Comment: Thank you. So to formalize this, would it be correct to state that, because there exists an x such that it is not a subset of B, the original statement would be false?

Comment: We write "$A \subseteq B$" if and only if "$x \in A$ implies $x \in B$". If we can find one $x \in A$ such that $x \notin B$, then $A \nsubseteq B$.

Answer (score 2):

The set $[7,10)$ is an interval and contains an infinite number of elements: all real numbers from 7 included to 10 excluded. That makes an infinity of numbers. Set theorists say that there are more real numbers in any  one unit long interval than in the whole ( infinite) set of natural numbers.

See: § " Sets with the cardinality of the continuum". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum

The set $\{7,8,9,10\}$ only has 4 elements, and is therefore a finite set.

An infinite set cannot be a subset of a finite set.

As a finite set the set $\{7,8,9,10\}$ could be a subset of $[7,10)$ , but it's not the case, since it is not true that all the elements of $\{7,8,9,10\}$ are also elements of $[7,10)$.

True, the numbers 7, 8, 9 are also elements of $[7,10)$, but number 10 is not.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your interval $I$.
Intuitively, you can think of sets as bags that don't contain duplicated items.
If $A$ out-contain every items in the bag $I$ then we say $I \subset A$.
In your example, you have listed some elements that existed in the $I$ but not in the set $A$. And thus, $I \not\subset A$.

Since you said you're learning elementary set theory, it's a good habit to ask yourself whether $I \subset A$ or not.
And if you have learned about the intersection operation $\cap$ then you could try to ask what is $I \cap A$. And then try to do the same with examples where there are subsets relation, maybe equal set relation. You'll find it make much more sense :)

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation definitely helped. I'll be learning about intersections soon, so I'll definitely make sure to apply your perspective. I'm highly curious to see how this all relates and unfolds!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely and definitely **no**!

The set $A=\{7, 8, 9, 10\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ and has only **four elements**, this is the four **integers** $7$, $8$, $9$ and $10$.

The set $B=[7, 10)$ is meant to be a real interval, it is the set of all the **real** numbers $x$ such that $7\le x<10$.

The cardinality of $A=\{7, 8, 9, 10\}$ is $4$, while the cardinality of $B=[7,10)$ is the same of $\mathbb{R}$, which is **infinite** and it is even a bigger infinite (*cardinality of the continuum*) than the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$.

Notice that $10$ is an element of $A$ but not of $B$, while any irrational number between $7$ and $10$ belongs to $B$ but not to $A$.

If $B$ was a subset of $A$, this would mean that $B\cap A=B$. But in this case we have that
$$
B\cap A=\{7,8,9\}
$$
is a non-trivial subset of both $A$ and $B$.

I think this question rised from an uncomplete understanding of the notation: $[a,b]$, $[a,b)$, $(a,b]$ and $(a,b)$ denote *connected* subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, while $\{a,\ldots,b\}$ an unconnected one.